# I am getting black Laplacian of Guassian image

Tags: python, image-processing, filtering, laplacianofgaussian

```
import cv2
import math
```

**gaussian function**

```
def gaussianblur(img,sigma):
      if(sigma<0):
        print("SIGMA SHOULD BE POSITIVE")
        return;
```

calculating 1 dimensional kernal with g(x)=(1/squareroot(2*sigma*sigma*3.142)) * e^(-(x*x)/(2*sigma*sigma))

```
      deno=(((math.sqrt(2*3.142*sigma*sigma))))
      k=[0,0,0,0,0]
      sum=0




      for x in range(-2,3):
       numo=(math.exp(-((x*x)/(2*(sigma*sigma)))))
       k[x+2]=(numo/deno)
       sum=sum+k[x+2]




      for x in range(0,5):
        k[x]=(k[x]/sum)
```

applying convolution row by row

```
      for i in range(0,img.shape[0]):
       for j in range(2,img.shape[1]-2):
            img[i,j]=abs((img[i,j-2]*k[0])+(img[i,j-1]*k[1])+(img[i,j]*k[2])+(img[i,j+1]*k[3])+(img[i,j+2]*k[4]))



      return img;  `#end of gaussian blur function`
```

**main function start**

read image

```
dog=img = cv2.imread('art.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

apply 1 st blur

```
temp=img=gaussianblur(img,1)

#display image
cv2.imshow('blur1',img)
```

apply 2nd blur

```
temp=gaussianblur(temp,1)

cv2.imshow('blur2',temp)
```

the difference of Gaussian

```
for i in range(0,img.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0,img.shape[1]):
       dog[i,j]=abs((img[i,j])-(temp[i,j]))

cv2.imshow('DoG',dog)
```

> output

[blur1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuvWG.png)

[blur2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkZyf.png)

[DoG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib9H9.png)

Comment: you can refer http://www.tjscientific.com/2017/01/31/using-python-and-opencv-to-create-a-difference-of-gaussian-filter/

Comment: actually, i wanted to implement Gaussian blur without built-in function.

Comment: Try calling `normalize()` prior to displaying your image in case the values are diminishingly small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your input here:

```
for i in range(0,img.shape[0]):
    for j in range(2,img.shape[1]-2):
        img[i,j]=abs((img[i,j-2]*k[0])+(img[i,j-1]*k[1])+(img[i,j]*k[2])+(img[i,j+1]*k[3])+(img[i,j+2]*k[4]))
```

Try writing the result to a new image.

I do not know how the OpenCV python interface works, does `temp=img` cause `temp` to share the data with `img` (as in, when you change the one you also change the other)? Make sure you have two different data blocks!

Comment: temp = np.zeros((img.shape[0],img.shape[1],1), np.uint8) to create a new empty image with same dimension as your original image.

Comment: I got the result, that was very helpful, thank u @ Cris Luengo